# MATLAB - literally convert decimal to string

Tags: matlab

I hope I have a simple question, I just couldn't figure it out.

I have several numbers which I want to be converted to string quite literally:

```
12.000 -> '12.000'
4.0 -> '4.0'
34.760000 -> '34.760000'
```

As you can see, I cannot simply pad zeros, since that highly depends on how many zero are given with the number.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How do you know how many zeros were given? `a=1.0; b=1.00000; a==b` gives `true`. MATLAB doesn’t record how many zeros were originally given, the numbers are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, yes, this is easily accomplished with MATLAB's [num2str](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) function, like so:

```
num2str(12.000 ,'%.3f')
num2str(4.0, '%.1f')
num2str(34.760000,'%.6f')
```

WRT " %*x*.f ", where *x* equals 3,1, and 6 in the examples above, this is called the `formSpec`, which I would encourage you to read about more, [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html?searchHighlight=format%20specification&s_tid=srchtitle#btf_bfy-1_sep_shared-formatSpec). In this case, we are saying that the variable is a floating point number, and we want to preserve *x* digits after the decimal place. It is useful to know about format specification for parsing text, and to efficiently read from and write to files.

**Edit:** A point of clarification, and as I'm sure you already know, single quotes (' ') in MATLAB yield a character array rather than a string. These are different data types. If you're really after a string, just add `string` to the `num2str` argument, i.e.,

```
string(num2str(12.000 ,'%.3f'))
string(num2str(4.0, '%.1f'))
string(num2str(34.760000,'%.6f'))
```

Comment: But what if I don't yet how much zeros are given as input? For example: user 1 will may type 12.00 while user 2 types 12.000. The string I want from this would be '12.00' and '12.000'. So is it possible to literally convert this number to a string?

Comment: Yes, I anticipated this might be your case. So the question then becomes, "what are you doing with these values afterward?" Do you need a certain level of precision for subsequent computations? `num2str` also takes a precision argument, which will keep the specified number of significant figures. (Also: Why don't you take the input as a string to begin with?)

Comment: I want to iterate over several numbers (with +1 for example after each loop), which is kinda hard when I have strings.

Comment: I don't understand why that matters. An element is an element...if it's of type double or string (not a character vector) then I don't see how looping behaviour would be affected. It's difficult to provide further guidance without understanding what you are trying to achieve in more detail.

Comment: It matters because the input file, where this number is added as a string, only works when there are a specific amount of zero's added to the number. This means that for the number 12 for example, the input can only handle 12.000.